# Write and save HTML in Excel with VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

looking for help as I have not found anything on this specific topic yet.

***Goal:*** I would like to write HTML style directly in Excel, press a button and have the generated html file with the writen output opened.

***Background:*** I know that this sound odd, but I have a lot of data coming in from sql queries. These are then calculated, sorted and filtered in excel. To visualize these I w transform the outputs directly in html format in the spreadsheet (I know that this task could be done with php much quicker - but unfortunately this is not granted in my company).

All attempts from my were to write VBA to save the spreadsheet as html. But Excel always tried visualize the whole sheet into html and not just the plain html code written down in the sheet.

very simpliefied, this is the whats entered in a regular excel spreadsheet between A1:A8

```
<!DOCTYPE

<htm>

<body>


<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png" alt=stack" width="50" height="60">



</body> </html>
```

Hope this sounds not to wired :)
Thanks for any help!
Kris

Comment: so you have the above in range A1:A8 and you want what as output?

Comment: Yea - just the plain code saved in to a file allowing g to be saved/opened as html

Comment: `alt=stack"` should be `alt="stack"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a           As Variant

a = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

a = Convert2DArrayTo1DArray(a)
ArrayToTextFile a, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.html"
End Sub

Function Convert2DArrayTo1DArray(arr As Variant)
Dim b()         As Variant
Dim s           As String
Dim i           As Long

ReDim b(1 To UBound(arr, 1))

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    b(i) = arr(i, 1)
Next i

Convert2DArrayTo1DArray = b
End Function

Function ArrayToTextFile(a As Variant, strPath As String)
Dim fso         As Object
Dim fn          As Object
Dim i           As Long

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fn = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath, 2, True)

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    fn.writeline a(i)
Next i

fn.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry as English is not my native language. The code is simply exports the data in column A to html file   I supposed that the lines of html in A1:A8

Comment: This is awesome , thank you Yasser! Works as desired. One last question (for me as VBA noob): What would I need to add if I would wanted to open the sample.html after saving it?
Many thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at this [LINK](https://excel.tips.net/T002003_Opening_an_HTML_Page_in_a_Macro.html)