# How to write and save a range of Excel cells as separate HTML files

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

To explain, I am creating a set of professional email signatures in Outlook365 and am attempting to create them uniformly, with only user contact details differing (naturally).

To do this, I have our users' data in a table and I will populate a cell for each row with HTML code, dynamically changing each row's information, making a unique, templated signature for each user.

The part I am struggling to find however is a piece of code which will take each cell's data and generate a HTML file for every individual cell. To clarify: I expect 200 cells would generate 200 HTML documents, all from the 'HTML' column of my Excel sheet.

| Name | Email address | Phone number | HTML |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | jb@website.com | 079998 | `<table style="width: ...` |
| Billy Bloggs | bb@website.com | 079999 | `<table style="width: ...` |
| Phil Bloggs | pb@website.com | 080000 | `<table style="width: ...` |

I have looked at other queries on this site and I believe VBA can handle this, however the VBA I have tried has only taken *a table of data* and made it a HTML file, or even a [column of cells into a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083026/write-and-save-html-in-excel-with-vba). I am really hoping someone can help identify a way to simply write each cell to its own HTML file on my local drive.

Comment: The linked question seems to be specifically creating a single document from a range, and I am requesting many documents from a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works with the sheet you start it from. I used the name column for the file names. Change it like you need it.

This is how to save each cell of a column to a single file:

```
Sub WriteCellHTML()

Const colToWrite As Long = 4
Const colToFileName As Long = 1
Const firstRow As Long = 2
Const path As String = "E:\Test\" 'don't forget the backslash at the end
Dim currRow As Long

  currRow = firstRow
  
  Do Until Cells(currRow, colToFileName) = ""
    Close
    Open path & Cells(currRow, colToFileName) & ".htm" For Output As #1
    Print #1, Cells(currRow, colToWrite)
    Close
    currRow = currRow + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```